# Good Asset Management or File Tagging software recommendations?

Tags: file-management, digital-asset-management, asset-management, tags

I have been collecting all kinds of free and paid game assets for years now, everything from sound FX to art to system scripts to tools etc. Problem is it's basically impossible to find anything anymore - they're all spread across different drives and are for different kinds of projects and engines and game types.

I've looked into DAMs but they tend to be on the enterprise side, a lot of the tagging systems are too simple or only document based or require a monthly sub for more than X amount of tags/files.

I'm a Windows user, but I also have a 2TB Google Drive account, so if anyone has a way of integrating that, I'd be very interested.

What do you all do for managing all of your assets in a more streamlined and convenient way?

Thanks!

PS. Should also mention I'm talking about 100,000s of files.